# Multiple keys for redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to use objects to decide what part of my reducer is run. My current example is mainly from the redux docs. Example:

```
export const todos = createReducer(initialState, {
    [ADD_TODO]: function (state, action) {
        return [ ...state, text: action.text ]
    }
})

function createReducer(initialState, handlers) {
    return function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
        if (handlers.hasOwnProperty(action.type)) {
            return handlers[action.type](state, action)
        } 

        return state;
    }
}
```

This works fine for most use-cases but I would prefer to have the same function run for multiple actions. For example in a typical reducer I would do the following:

```
case: ADD_TODO:
case: ADD_TODOS:
    // Do stuff and return state
    return [ ...state, text: action.text ]
```

I want to be able to do something like:

```
createReducer(initialState, {
    [ADD_TODO, ADD_TODOS]: function (state, action) { 
        // do stuff
```

Any ideas for a clean approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to define the function separately, and reuse it for multiple keys:

```
function addTodo(state, action) {
    // do stuff
}

export default createReducer(initialState, {
    [ADD_TODO] : addTodo,
    [ADD_TODOS] : addTodo,
});
```